# Jquery code for one page portfolio

Tags: jquery

I am using following jquery code for my one page portfolio

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav ul li a').click(function(){
        var el = $(this).attr('href');
        var elWrapped = $(el);
        scrollToDiv(elWrapped,140);
        return false;

    });

    function scrollToDiv(element,navheight){
          var offset = element.offset();
          var offsetTop = offset.top;
          var totalScroll = offsetTop-navheight;
          $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: totalScroll
        }, 650);
    }
});
</script>
```

[link](http://www.hettzdesigns.com)

but when page loads it directly goes to contact section of site instead of index section.

Can anyone tell where it is going wrong.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha - Why?

Answer (score 2):

You are giving an autofocus to the textarea.

```
<textarea type="textarea" name="message" id="message" rows=9 required autofocus /></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sections are not a problem here. The problem is that the `Name` textbox is getting focus on load, and the page is automatically scrolled to show this field.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried clicking your link as posted in your question, and by using Chrome, it shows the behavior that you're talking about, while on the other hand, when I did the same in IE 10, such behavior doesn't show.

Checking in the source of your site, the textbox with ID='name' has an **autofocus** property.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="" autofocus="">
```

Please see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) for more information.